# Undelete files on only /home/ disk encryption

Tags: files, encryption, undelete

I recently installed xubuntu with /home/ encryption on one of my partitions. I would like to know:

1. Can files deleted normally be recovered?
2. How can I safely overwrite already deleted files in /home/?

I tried testdisk, what gave me the normal "Directory unmounted to protect your files" message.

Thanks

Comment: please could you elaborate on what you mean by __safely overwrite already deleted files__ . Are you talking of similarly named files in `/home/` ?

Comment: With "safely overwrite already deleted files" I mean, I can't use tools like wipe, because the file is already deleted "unsafely", I want it to be overwritten.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. `shred` them maybe

Comment: look [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tools-to-delete-files-securely-in-ubuntu-linux.html)

Comment: I cant find any tools that allow secure ereasing when the tool is *alredy* deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Files that are deleted "normally" are actually just moved to a Trash folder. If you haven't emptied your trash folder, you can use tools like shred to wipe them. If you have already emptied your trash folder, then the remanents of those files could be anywhere on the disk partition that holds your home directory. You can use shred to wipe an entire disk partition, but that may not be practical if your home and root directories are on the same partition. If your /home directory is on a separate partition, you can probably boot into single user mode and then run shred on the entire partition where /home directories are (this will eliminate ALL data there, including your and other peoples home directories). Back it all up before trying this.